# RadDateInput not in the correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, telerik

I have a rad input that accepts dates only in the format specified, this works fine but when i try to convert it to datetime on the back end (in c# code) it says its not in the correct format.

```
 <telerik:RadDateInput ID="DeliveryDate" runat="server" 
  MinDate="1/1/1980" MaxDate="12/31/2099" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" Visible="false">

// Throws an error that its not in the correct format
DateTime Test = Convert.ToDateTime(DeliveryDate.Text);
```

When I add a break point at the DateTime line the text is being passed in this format (i dont know why if i specified MM/dd/yyyy).

```
2012-02-03 00:00:00
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime test = DeliveryDate.SelectedDate` instead

Comment: It is also a good practise to check DeliveryDate.SelectedDate.HasValue in order to avoid exceptions.